# pressing the graph causes the application to crash

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I have a question, how do I turn on the application on the phone and try to press the graph from MPAndroidChart, it throws me from the application and I write that the application is crashing.

link to the page from which I took the documentation [here][1]

I have a problem with the chart. My chart takes data from a csv file and gives the time in hours, minutes and seconds. How to calibrate the graph so that the time is displayed every 60 minutes instead of every 100 minutes
MY

MainActivity

```
package com.example.aplikacjadlataty

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Switch
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.Easing
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            val lines = readCSV(uri)
            val newEntries = lines.map { line -> toEntry(line) }.groupingBy { entry -> entry.x }
                .reduce { _, accumulator, element -> if (accumulator.y > element.y) accumulator else element }.values
            val lineChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.lineChart)
            val vl = LineDataSet(newEntries.toList().take(4000), "cost")
            vl.setDrawValues(false)
            vl.setDrawFilled(true)
            vl.lineWidth = 1.5f
            vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
            vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red
            vl.setDrawCircles(false)
            lineChart.data = LineData(vl)
            lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
            lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)
            lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
            lineChart.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
            lineChart.isScaleYEnabled = false
            lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
//            lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = MyAxisFormatter()
//              lineChart.xAxis.granularity = 60f
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_loadCsv)?.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            intent.type = "text/*"
            getContent.launch("text/*")
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_loadCsv)
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

        val sw1 = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
        sw1?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            else screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

            if (isChecked) layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            else layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

            if (isChecked) AdsLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            else AdsLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

            if (isChecked) text.text = "Set light mode"
            else text.text = "Set dark mode"
            if (isChecked) text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            else text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)

            if (isChecked) button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            else button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            if (isChecked) button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#707070"))
            else button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#efefef"))
        }

        Log.d(
            "MainActivity", "onCreate Called \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "    __  ___    ___     __ __   _____          ______    __  __   ____        __    _   __    ____    ___     __ __  \n" +
                    "   /  |/  /   /   |   / //_/  / ___/         / ____/   / / / /  / __ \\      / /   / | / /   /  _/   /   |   / //_/ \n" +
                    "  / /|_/ /   / /| |  / ,<     \\__ \\         / /       / /_/ /  / / / / __  / /   /  |/ /    / /    / /| |  / ,<   \n" +
                    " / /  / /   / ___ | / /| |   ___/ /        / /___    / __  /  / /_/ / / /_/ /   / /|  /   _/ /    / ___ | / /| |    \n" +
                    "/_/  /_/   /_/  |_|/_/ |_|  /____/         \\____/   /_/ /_/   \\____/  \\____/   /_/ |_/   /___/   /_/  |_|/_/ |_| \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                      "
        )

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

        val markerView = CustomMarker(this@MainActivity, R.layout.marker_view)
        lineChart.marker = markerView
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun readCSV(uri: Uri?): List<String> {
        if (uri != null) {
            val csvFile = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val isr = InputStreamReader(csvFile)
            return BufferedReader(isr).readLines()
        }
        return Collections.emptyList()
    }

    private fun toEntry(line: String): Entry {
        val split = line.split(";")
        return Entry(split[1].toFloat(), split[2].toFloat())
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody could help you if you don't log the crash or the code

Comment: Post a code, not a photos

Comment: We need the crash log, write as a code and not as an Image/photos etc. COuld be better copy and paste code to test it in our software

Comment: Thanks. On witch part the app crash? Do you have the cause of the crash? Could you provide some logs about the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure is clear. It's specified here:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.example.aplikacjadlataty.CustomMarker.refreshContent(CustomMarker.kt:22)
```

So go to line 22 inside CustomMarker.kt and fix it. Probably you have not a reference to `tvPrice`. Do you know where is that ID?

**EDIT**

You can't do it if you don't read all the document. Do you have added this `.XML` in your project?

`marker_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oval_marker"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It's explained in your link, [here](https://medium.com/@yilmazvolkan/kotlinlinecharts-c2a730226ff1)

EDIT 2 
Follow my code. For me i's working well:

Below `MainActivity.kt`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.Easing
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val lineChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.lineChart)

        //Part1
        val entries = ArrayList<Entry>()

//Part2
        entries.add(Entry(1f, 10f))
        entries.add(Entry(2f, 2f))
        entries.add(Entry(3f, 7f))
        entries.add(Entry(4f, 20f))
        entries.add(Entry(5f, 16f))

//Part3
        val vl = LineDataSet(entries, "My Type")

//Part4
        vl.setDrawValues(false)
        vl.setDrawFilled(true)
        vl.lineWidth = 3f
        vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
        vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red

//Part5
        lineChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 0f

//Part6
        lineChart.data = LineData(vl)

//Part7
        lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.axisMaximum = 1 + 0.1f

//Part8
        lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true)
        lineChart.setPinchZoom(true)

//Part9
        lineChart.description.text = "Days"
        lineChart.setNoDataText("No forex yet!")

//Part10
        lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)

//Part11
        val markerView = CustomMarker(this, R.layout.marker_view)
        lineChart.marker = markerView
    }
}
```

Below `CustomMarker.kt`

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.TextView
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF

class CustomMarker(context: Context, layoutResource: Int):  MarkerView(context, layoutResource) {
    override fun refreshContent(entry: Entry?, highlight: Highlight?) {
        val value = entry?.y?.toDouble() ?: 0.0

        val tvPrice = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPrice)

        val resText: String = if(value.toString().length > 8){
            "Val: " + value.toString().substring(0,7)
        } else{
            "Val: $value"
        }
        tvPrice.text = resText
        super.refreshContent(entry, highlight)
    }

    override fun getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint(xpos: Float, ypos: Float): MPPointF {
        return MPPointF(-width / 2f, -height - 10f)
    }
}
```

Here `activity_main.xml` inside `res/layout` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="9dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here `oval_marker.xml` inside `res/drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/gray" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorWhite" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

Here `gradient_bg.xml` inside `drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorLight"
                android:endColor="@color/colorDark"
                android:angle="180"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here `colors.xml` inside `res/values`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>

    <color name="green">#4CAF50</color>
    <color name="red">#F44336</color>
    <color name="colorDark">#666262</color>
    <color name="colorLight">#F3D3D0</color>
    <color name="gray">#4E4948</color>
    <color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: has you a reference about xml inside your marker class?

Comment: in your ActivityMain replace  CustomMarker(this@MainActivity, R.layout.activity_main) with CustomMarker(this@MainActivity, R.layout.marker_view)

Comment: @MaksChojniak check out my new edit 2. You will have all the code you need to try the demo

Comment: this is not fain. You can't unaccept if you have new problem!

Comment: I can't ask a new question :(